# how can i make this menu display, like as per in the image using media query?

Tags: html, css

how can i make this menu display, like as per in the image using media query [image]

This is what i done now [codepen link](http://codepen.io/nikhilrajnair/pen/PZxYzX)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="menu-tags">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">STARTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BREAKFAST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LUNCH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DINNER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DESERTS</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks same as image. What changes you need?

Comment: @ketan, please check with resizing the browser window.. the last menu should be in center, currently its not in center.

Comment: resize your browser into different resolutions to see it happening

Comment: make it display as per in the image , now its not like that actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make li as `display:inline-block;` and add `text-align:center` to `ul`

```
.menu-tags ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: list-item;  
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-tags li {
    display: inline-block;

}
.menu-tags a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-tags ul li a {
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none; color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;   
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    font-family: "Josefin sans",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu-tags ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F1CD8F !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-tags{
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjGBLE

Comment: i'm tried with display:inline-block  but it  produces output like in your codepen , i need the output as per in the image

Comment: what is the difference between both of them

Comment: This is the correct answer, and to make it *EXACTLY* like the image - just remove the right left padding from the links: `.menu-tags ul li a {padding:2px 0 5px;}` see my [codepen fork](http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/jWQNJM)

Answer (score 0):

**View the snippet in full screen:**

Set width for `<li>` elements and remove float for last `<li>`.

```
.menu-tags li {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;  
        text-align: center;
 }
 .menu-tags ul > li:last-child {
        float: none;
        margin: auto;
  }
```

**Try the below code:**

```css
.menu-tags ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: list-item;  
}
.menu-tags li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.menu-tags ul > li:last-child {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu-tags a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-tags ul li a {
    display: inline-block;    
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none; color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;   
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    font-family: "Josefin sans",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu-tags ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F1CD8F !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-tags{
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="menu-tags">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">STARTER</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BREAKFAST</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LUNCH</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DINNER</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DESERTS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by this, deserts will be always in middle. It should be depend on resizing means in media queries...

Comment: The above code is for normal view. In responsive you have to set code in media queries

Comment: And that's the problem man.. that's why op said how to do with media queries.. he did not ask how to take last menu in center.. please read full question then give answer. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

the correct css

```
.menu-tags ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: list-item;  
    }
    .menu-tags li {
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .menu-tags a:link{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menu-tags ul li a {
        display: inline-block;    
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none; color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
        cursor: pointer;   
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        font-family: "Josefin sans",sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
    .menu-tags ul li a:hover{
        border-bottom: 3px solid #F1CD8F !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menu-tags{
        padding-left: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```